# 'PasswordCredential' is not defined -> Create React Template

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working in the Create React template.

I'm getting the error message 'PasswordCredential' is not defined which is preventing compiling. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create-React linting software does not know PasswordCredential is an accessible global variable. You need to add it as a Global definitions with.

```
/*global PasswordCredential a*/
```

This will allow the linting software to know that the variable is accessible.